PWA handle notifications without push
I have this simple management app that i built and now i want to add notifications to it however i didn't want to use any push service I'm trying to do a simple fetch to my api evry 15 minutes and find if any new notifications are available then i show them to the user and log what has been shown using my service work to indexdb so that i don't swns the same notification twice, sounds fairly simple as i don't have any need for instant notification.
Here is my attempt :
sw.js
importScripts('/rss/umd.js');
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/5.1.2/workbox-sw.js');

const CACHE = "pwabuilder-offline-page-v001";
const OFFLINE_PAGE = "offline.html";
const NOTIFICATIONS_API = "/api/notifications";
const ICON_BASE_URL = "/storage/photos/users/";
const SYNC_INTERVAL = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 15 minutes

self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
  if (event.data?.type === "SKIP_WAITING") {
    self.skipWaiting();
  }
});

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE)
      .then((cache) => cache.add(OFFLINE_PAGE))
  );
});

if (workbox.navigationPreload.isSupported()) {
  workbox.navigationPreload.enable();
}

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('/rss/*'),
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: CACHE
  })
);

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate') {
    event.respondWith(handleFetchEvent(event));
  }
});

async function handleFetchEvent(event) {
  try {
    const preloadResp = await event.preloadResponse;
    if (preloadResp) return preloadResp;

    const networkResp = await fetch(event.request);
    return networkResp;
  } catch {
    const cache = await caches.open(CACHE);
    const cachedResp = await cache.match(OFFLINE_PAGE);
    return cachedResp;
  }
}

const dbPromise = idb.openDB('notification-store', 1, {
  upgrade(db) {
    if (!db.objectStoreNames.contains('notifications')) {
      db.createObjectStore('notifications', { keyPath: 'id' });
    }
  }
});

async function fetchNotifications() {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(NOTIFICATIONS_API);
    if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Failed to fetch notifications');

    const notifications = await response.json();
    for (const notification of notifications) {
      const sent = await isNotificationSent(notification.id);
      if (!sent) {
        self.registration.showNotification(notification.name, {
          body: notification.dec,
          icon: `${ICON_BASE_URL}${notification.sender_id}/avatar.jpg`
        });
        await markNotificationAsSent(notification.id);
      }
    }
  } catch {}
}

async function isNotificationSent(id) {
  const db = await dbPromise;
  const tx = db.transaction('notifications', 'readonly');
  const store = tx.objectStore('notifications');
  const notification = await store.get(id);
  return !!notification;
}

async function markNotificationAsSent(id) {
  const db = await dbPromise;
  const tx = db.transaction('notifications', 'readwrite');
  tx.objectStore('notifications').put({ id: id });
  await tx.done;
}

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil((async () => {
    setInterval(fetchNotifications, SYNC_INTERVAL);
    await fetchNotifications();
  })());
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', () => {});

self.addEventListener('sync', (event) => {
  if (event.tag === 'fetch-notifications') {
    event.waitUntil(fetchNotifications());
  }
});

This works on android while the app is running however once i close the app i no longer get any notification, On the other hand ios this did not work at all, i did add the app to the home screen and enabled notifications but it never triggered at all

"On the other hand ios this did work at all,"  Is there a "not"  missing in this sentence? And what do you mean by "close" in the android case? Just put it in the background? remove it from the task switcher?

@derpirscher yes sorry typo, even without removing it from task switcher simply by just using another app i don't get any new notifications
